# Как узнать, что блокирует прокрутку страницы колёсиком?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

На [сайте](http://www.movitek.ru/) не работает прокрутка страницы колёсиком мыши в Google Chrome 61 на Windows 10. В других браузерах всё работает нормально. Я запускал собственный jquery-скрипт для проверки выполнения события, но событие выполнялось, только если мышь была наведена на полосу прокрутки, тогда же и прокручивалась страница. Разворошив все скрипты, я нашёл в скрипте RD Parallax следующий код:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
                parallax.move();
            });
```

В отладчике до выполнения этого кода страница прокручивалась, а после - переставала. Сейчас я грешу на него, но чтобы простое назначение обработчика события вешало всю прокрутку? Выглядит странно.

Прошу подсказать мне, правильно ли я определил источник проблемы и что с ним делать дальше.

Answer (score 2):

Для версии хрома `Google Chrome 61.x.x` `window scroll` работать будет так:

```
$('html, body').bind('scroll', function () {
  parallax.move();
});
```

Так оно будет работать уже на всех браузерах.

Для той версии хрома `$(window).bind('scroll'` и `$('body').bind('scroll'` не работают.

Comment: Ага, и откуда же такая информация?

Comment: @Cheg Опыт дал, И поиск в гугле))))
Если думаете что не прав то можете дать свой ответ.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Cheg/pen/yzoJVb Google Chrome 61.0.3163.100 (x64) - работают все варианты, кроме вашего. Фантастика?

Comment: @Cheg можете проверить у человека, позже могу и видео скинуть про версию.